# Plotting multiple lines (line chart) in Apache Zeppelin using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to plot multiple line Charts in Apache Zeppelin using Angular Js and Chart JS. 
i am binding an array in the Scala Paragraph in the format                   {epoch, id, label, score, tweet_count}. The objective is for every id, there will be a different set of values. on running the code i am having two different graphs (on hovering mouse). i would like to have 1 graph.
For instance, for id 1,2 i would like to plot a score graph in the same canvas and not want it overlapped.

```
angular.forEach(newValue, function(x) {  
    lineChartData = {}; //declare an object
    lineChartData.labels = []; //add 'labels' element to object (X axis)
    lineChartData.datasets = []; //add 'datasets' array element to object


  for(line=0; line < 2; line++) {

            y = [];
            lineChartData.datasets.push({}); //create a new line dataset
            dataset = lineChartData.datasets[line]
            dataset.data = []; //Y axis data

            angular.forEach(newValue, function(x) {
                   if(myLineChart != null && myLineChart !== undefined)
        myLineChart.destroy();

                if (line === 0 ) {  

                   // console.log("Value of x: ",x)

                    //adds data to y axis
                    lineChartData.labels.push(x._3) //adds x axis labels

                    dataset.fillColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)";
                    dataset.strokeColor = "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)";
                    dataset.lineColor = "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)";
                    dataset.label = "Score"
                    y.push(x._4); //y axis value


                }

                lineChartData.datasets[line].data = y;   

             })
         }

    })
```

This is my code which plots the graph, but i would like to plot different lines for each id in the same canvas.

Answer (score 3):

We can do a model transformation from one DataSource (for example Spark DataFrame) to the Chart's model which `%angular` supported by Zeppelin. You can doing similar like this SO [create a multi line chart using Chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131275/create-a-multi-line-chart-using-chart-js)

> If doing this way, then every time when we want to change to a different model. We have to do copy & paste work. It will be easier if there is a general model transformation.

I created a repo on github **[spark-highcharts](https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts)** for plot easily for spark DataFrame with Highcharts. You can plot with spark-highcharts after doing a simple transformation from Scala collection to Spark DataFrame if you could accept using Highcharts.

Like the following code to create multiline chart.

```
import com.knockdata.spark.highcharts._
import com.knockdata.spark.highcharts.model._
import sqlContext.implicits._

val Tokyo = Seq(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6)
    .map(("Tokyo", _))
val NewYork = Seq(-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5)
  .map(("New York", _))
val Berlin = Seq(-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0)
  .map(("Berlin", _))
val London = Seq(3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8)
  .map(("London", _))

val dataFrame = (Tokyo ++ NewYork ++ Berlin ++ London).toDF("city", "temperature")

val chart = highcharts(dataFrame
  .seriesCol("city")
  .series("y" -> col("temperature")))

chart.plot()
```

[image: Multi Line Chart]

And the API is pretty similar between [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic) and [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-creating-a-chart). A similar library could be done to transform from Scala collection to ChartJs similar like [spark-highcharts](https://github.com/knockdata/spark-highcharts) does.

Comment: Thank you very much. and what if i tried a different approach,for instance i  run a cqlsh query in a different paragraph and get the plots. is there any way to run this query dynamically to plot the graph like a script(for every minute without me having to click and update the paragraph) or link it with angular paragraph

Comment: The easiest way shall be using [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector)

Comment: Where did the months on the X-axis come from?